# Java save XChart as a PDF

Tags: java, graph, charts, knowm-xchart

Using [XChart](http://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/xchart-example-code/) I can make nice graphs. When I make the graph, I can right-click it, and an option to "save as" comes up. Then, I can save the image in a specified format, to a specified directory by clicking around.

How could I write Java code that automates this for me? That is, I have an application that creates about fifty graphs, and I don't want to have to deal with manually saving each one where it belongs every time I run the app.

Here's how I make my chart:

```
private void makeLineChart(int[][] data, String title) {
    MyLineChart c = new MyLineChart(data, title);
    XYChart chart = c.getChart();
    new SwingWrapper<XYChart>(chart).displayChart();
    // save as pdf...?
}
```

Comment: [It does exist](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues/64) (a 3 year old issue), not sure _how_ though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code of xchart has the solution. BitmapEncoder can do that everytime you start your app.`BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.PNG);`

```
public class Example1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 double[] yData = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
// Create Chart
XYChart chart = new XYChart(500, 400);
chart.setTitle("Sample Chart");
chart.setXAxisTitle("X");
chart.setXAxisTitle("Y");
XYSeries series = chart.addSeries("y(x)", null, yData);
series.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.CIRCLE);

BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.PNG);
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.JPG);
BitmapEncoder.saveJPGWithQuality(chart, "./Sample_Chart_With_Quality.jpg", 0.95f);
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.BMP);
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./Sample_Chart", BitmapFormat.GIF);

BitmapEncoder.saveBitmapWithDPI(chart, "./Sample_Chart_300_DPI", BitmapFormat.PNG, 300);
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmapWithDPI(chart, "./Sample_Chart_300_DPI", BitmapFormat.JPG, 300);
BitmapEncoder.saveBitmapWithDPI(chart, "./Sample_Chart_300_DPI", BitmapFormat.GIF, 300);

VectorGraphicsEncoder.saveVectorGraphic(chart, "./Sample_Chart", VectorGraphicsFormat.EPS);
VectorGraphicsEncoder.saveVectorGraphic(chart, "./Sample_Chart", VectorGraphicsFormat.PDF);
VectorGraphicsEncoder.saveVectorGraphic(chart, "./Sample_Chart", VectorGraphicsFormat.SVG);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [dawnfyly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098530/320399), but a bit more specific to the OP's question and writes the output to a PDF only.

A PDF can be written using the [`VectorGraphicsEncoder`](https://github.com/knowm/XChart/blob/4646dda87b64a33b538ff8910a8d70e13eaeda1c/xchart/src/main/java/org/knowm/xchart/VectorGraphicsEncoder.java), which is shown in the examples under the heading ["Save Chart as Bitmap"](https://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/xchart-example-code/).

Here, I've slimmed down the example to just the relevant information:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.knowm.xchart.VectorGraphicsEncoder;
import org.knowm.xchart.VectorGraphicsEncoder.VectorGraphicsFormat;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYSeries;
import org.knowm.xchart.style.markers.SeriesMarkers;

public class TryXchartToPdf extends XchartBase {
    /**
     * Creates a simple Chart and saves it as a PDF file.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double[] yData = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

        // Create Chart
        XYChart chart = new XYChart(500, 400);
        chart.setTitle("Sample Chart");
        chart.setXAxisTitle("X");
        chart.setXAxisTitle("Y");
        XYSeries series = chart.addSeries("y(x)", null, yData);
        series.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.CIRCLE);

        VectorGraphicsEncoder.saveVectorGraphic(chart, "./Sample_Chart", VectorGraphicsFormat.PDF);

    }
}
```